# Current Of a Charged Rod at Constant Velocity

Tags: electromagnetism

Imagine you have a charged rod (more precisely, a charged line), with uniformly distributed total charge q, moving through space at a constant velocity v. What would be the resulting current from said moving charges? I thought that it would just be q*v, but current has units of coulombs per second, and charge times velocity would result in units of coulombs * meters per second, which doesn't add up.

Comment: Is the direction of motion parallel to the axis of the rod?

Comment: Yes, does that make a difference?

Comment: Yes, in general the current through some surface would depend on the direction of motion of the rod.

Answer (score 3):

Let $L$ be the length of the rod. The charge per unit length of the rod is $q/L$. Now imagine a surface through which you want to calculate the current. Suppose the rod is passing through the surface and is normal to it (this second assumption isn't actually necessary, it might just help you picture it). During a time interval $\Delta t$, a portion of the rod of length $v\Delta t$ passes through the surface, carrying a charge of $qv\Delta t/L$. The current is the charge passing through the surface per unit time, which is $qv/L$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's find the  current density as in this situation I believe its more appropriate.

$\vec{J} = \rho \vec{V}$

Where $\rho$ is charge density, not charge. (Q/m^3)

$\rho$ = total charge/volume

Once you find the current density this should give you enough information to find the corresponding magnetic field.

However if for some reason you'd want to find the current through a cross sectional area of the rod, then compute the flux integral of $\vec{J}$ about your chosen cross section.

P.s if $\vec{V}$ is not parrallel to axis of the rod, then I would not even attempt to find current  and instead use current density. If the velocity is parrallel to the axis  simply multiply $|\vec{J}|$ by the area of your rod to find current.